# R colnames() assigning every element in list to first column

Tags: r, r-colnames

I am trying to rename the 104 columns in a dataframe (df) using a list or character vector (I've tried it both ways).

Instead of assigning the 104 elements in the vector or list to the 104 columns one each, it assigns all 104 elements to the first column, and all others get NA.

Any suggestions as to why this behavior and how to do it correctly?

```
> names(df)


 [1] "V1"   "V2"   "V3"   "V4"   "V5"   "V6"   "V7"   "V8"   "V9"   "V10"  "V11"  "V12"  "V13"  "V14"  "V15"  "V16"  "V17"  "V18"  "V19"  "V20"  "V21"  "V22"  "V23"  "V24"  "V25"  "V26"  "V27" 
 [28] "V28"  "V29"  "V30"  "V31"  "V32"  "V33"  "V34"  "V35"  "V36"  "V37"  "V38"  "V39"  "V40"  "V41"  "V42"  "V43"  "V44"  "V45"  "V46"  "V47"  "V48"  "V49"  "V50"  "V51"  "V52"  "V53"  "V54" 
 [55] "V55"  "V56"  "V57"  "V58"  "V59"  "V60"  "V61"  "V62"  "V63"  "V64"  "V65"  "V66"  "V67"  "V68"  "V69"  "V70"  "V71"  "V72"  "V73"  "V74"  "V75"  "V76"  "V77"  "V78"  "V79"  "V80"  "V81" 
 [82] "V82"  "V83"  "V84"  "V85"  "V86"  "V87"  "V88"  "V89"  "V90"  "V91"  "V92"  "V93"  "V94"  "V95"  "V96"  "V97"  "V98"  "V99"  "V100" "V101" "V102" "V103" "V104"

> d2 = as.character(strapply(name,"(?<=[0-9]{1}=)(.{2,}?)((?= V[0-9])|(?=   $))",perl=TRUE))
> d2
[1] "c(\"ICPSR MEMBER ID NUMBER\", \"CONGRESS\", \"CHAMBER/CLASS\", \"STATE\", \"DISTRICT\", \"PARTY\", \"POL PARTY\", \"FULL NAME\", \"SEX\", \"REGION\", \"STATE BORN ..... \"ICPSR STUDY NUMBER\", \"ICPSR VERSION NUMBER\", \"ICPSR PART NUMBER\")"

 > class(d2)
 [1] "character"
 > colnames(df2) = d2
 > head(df2,1)


 c("ICPSR MEMBER ID NUMBER", "CONGRESS", "CHAMBER/CLASS", "STATE", "DISTRICT", "PARTY", "POL PARTY", "FULL NAME", "SEX", "REGION", "STATE BORN (ICPSR CODE)", "BORN/REP SAME STATE", "BORN/REP SAME REGION", "ICPSR RELATIVES CODE", "RELATIVES CLLPS", "SE ...
    1 

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1
  NA NA NA NA  NA NA                        NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA NA NA
```

Comment: Don't wrap d2 in `as.character`... you're making a single string out of the vector of new names...

Comment: So if I don't, it generates a list.  If I apply the list it has the same behavior.

Comment: Change the list into a vector and then assign it. `?unlist`

Comment: ?unlist did the trick.  Thanks Michael and Justin for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a vector of labels and then assign it to the data frame, no need for `as.character`.

```
labels <- c("ICPSR MEMBER ID NUMBER", "CONGRESS")
colnames(df) <- labels
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your response - d2 is a character vector.  When I apply it using colnames(df) <-d2, it assigns all the elements to the first column, and all others are NA.  Maybe I should mention that d2 is pulling the names from a string of variable names stored in name.

Comment: Make sure d2 is actually a vector, it looks like it is just a single character string (try eliminating `as.character`). It should take the format of my labels variable above.

Comment: c("ICPSR MEMBER ID NUMBER", "CONGRESS", "CHAMBER/CLASS", "STATE", "DISTRICT", "PARTY", "POL PARTY", "FULL NAME", "SEX", "REGION", "STATE BORN (I...  Michael - when it puts the names into the first column name, this is how it appears.  Which seems to match your format.

Comment: Nope, your code `"c(\"ICPSR MEMBER ID ...\")"` says what was once a vector of strings is now a single string. (because you wrapped `strapply` with `as.character`:  `as.character(c('a', 'b'))`.  Instead,  use `unlist(strapply(...))`.